# enable offline files for all the PC which are part of Security Group

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, group-policy, windows-10

I'm setting up a Home Folder to be available offline per device

The Drive which this folder will be connect to will be H:

This is What I have done.

- Create a Group Called Offline Devices, Add All of the device which should have H drive available as offline for user (Any User which login to this device)
- Then Setup Group policy which should have allow this but for some reason its not put the files offline.
- User can sync with server to allow offline files replicate back to server or download new available files by them self or system does it for them

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0KCtq.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IzTp.png)
I know the group policies are located in the computer configuration>Policies>administrative templates>Network> but I cant see any place to select which drives will be offline files

PC which this policy will be apply to
Windows 7, 8 and 10

Server DC: 2008 R2 and 2012 R2

Is they anything i'm missing

Comment: This GPO setting doesn't make any particular drive or folder available offline and there's no setting to do so. This setting enables Offline Files, nothing more. The user has to choose which folders they want to be available offline. It's not clear what your ultimate goal is but you might be better served by using Folder Redirection.

Comment: That's not true, You can setup folder for offline and then you use GPO to apply that settings

Comment: What?..........

Answer (score 0):

The place you define it is in the **Caching** tab of the **Advanced setting** tab in the Share itself.

[image]

Comment: I have done that. Still same problem